# Free standing cooker, smoke from top when cooker is switched on. How to stop smoke?

Tags: appliances

I have an electric beko bdc5422a free standing cooker (not fan assisted).  I received it second hand a year ago but I think it was bought around 10 years ago.  There are two tubes that come up from inside the cooker and to the back of a vent on the top of the cooker.  One tube comes from the oven and one from the grill.  The inside of the cooker was cleaned.  However, when I switch on the cooker there is a lot of smoke that comes out of the vent at the top, from the tubes from the oven.  What is causing the smoke and how can I fix it?

Comment: Smoke and electrics are not good.  Can you tell us the smell of the smoke.  Burnt meat/fat might just mean the cleaning was not good enough.  Plastic/mechanical smell means there is a problem and used should be stopped till fixed.  You do not want a fire.

Comment: Did you clean out the tubes? There might still be accumulated grease there. But yes, smoking electrical appliance means do not use until you have found out what's smoking.

Comment: a lot of times, cleaning an oven smears a thin coat of grease over everything inside, a thin coat that's quick to turn to smoke when heated. In short, there could be nothing wrong, this isn't necessarily a smoking gun pointing to immanent fire or destruction.

Comment: thanks.  I lifted the hob up and noticed there was a small blob of burnt grease under the vent by the tubes.  I've now cleaned that and the problem has gone away.  Crazy that such a small amount of charred gunk can cause so much smoking.